# How to load DICOM files in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, dicom, pydicom

I am trying to figure out the basics of importing DICOM files in Python using pydicom. While trying really simple code, I get following errors:

For code:
    import dicom

```
filePath="C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\dicom\testfiles"
ds=dicom.read_file(filePath[0])
```

I get error: 
    C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/041213/PycharmProjects/D/Deki.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/041213/PycharmProjects/D/Deki.py", line 4, in 
        ds=dicom.read_file(filePath[0])
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\dicom\filereader.py", line 589, in           read_file
        fp = open(fp, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'

I am using Python 3.4, pydicom 0.9.9 and JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2
If anyone can help me with this, or even just help me how to load a DICOM file in general, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you're passing the first char of the string (`C`) instead of the full string. Just do:

```
ds=dicom.read_file(filePath)
```

next error you'll stumble into: use *raw* prefix or `\t` gets interpreted as a tabulation character:

```
filePath=r"C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\dicom\testfiles"
         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use and \ escape character to avoid issues with tab and other special characters. Also remember when you do filePath[0] on a string it returns the first character

```
filePath="C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\dicom\\testfiles"
ds=dicom.read_file(filePath)
```